# CentOS 7 escape key mapping?

Tags: centos, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop

I reinstalled a bunch of GNOME packages for my CentOS 7 desktop and it fixed several issues I was having but now I'm having some weirdness with the <kbd>escape</kbd> key. Basically I press the <kbd>escape</kbd> key and it launches that app view like OSX mission control.

So every app I'm in when I'm trying to exit a dialog box (like cancelling an auto-complete box in an IDE) it just goes to app switch mode. I tried `xmodmap -e 'keycode 9 = '` but it just seemed to completely disable the <kbd>escape</kbd> key.I tried `xmodmap -e 'keycode 9 = Escape'` and it went back to the app-switch behavior. I can't seem to figure out what's causing this key to trigger that view mode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found in the Tweaks tool under Keyboard and Mouse there's a setting called 'Switch between overview and desktop' which was not assigned to anything. Once I selected an option from the dropdown it released the escape key from the app switch view.